# Gradle Tasks depends on a file which should not exist yet

Tags: java, gradle, task

I want to have a Gradle Tasks that executes my freshly build Java application. Also it should output the log/sout to a file called **servicedispatcher.out**. The problem that occurs is that Gradle, even tho I let this task depend on **copyDistributionsToDestination** (which would've created the missing filepath the error complains about) it still evaluates the Tasks code before the task dependency. This way I have no chance to define this path as the log output path. What can I do to get around this?

*Given the following code:*

```
task startDispatcher(type:Exec){
    workingDir = "servicedispatcher/bin/"
    commandLine "cmd", "/c", "servicedispatcher.bat"
    File logFile = file("${workingDir}/log/toolbox-components-servicedispatcher.out")
    if(logFile.exists() == false){
        logFile.createNewFile() // Line 75 of error message
    }
    standardOutput = new FileOutputStream("${workingDir}/log/servicedispatcher.out")
}

task startToolbox(){
    group "Toolbox"
    dependsOn copyDistributionsToDestination
    dependsOn startDispatcher
}

startDispatcher.mustRunAfter("copyDistributionsToDestination")
```

Error Message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Development\Testzone\toolbox-backend\build.gradle' line: 75

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'toolbox-backend'.
> Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.32 secs
Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden
19:19:48: External task execution finished ':startToolbox'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe do the file creation in the execution phase? Like

```
doFirst {
    if(!logFile.exists()) {
        logFile.createNewFile()
    }
}
```

Then it also is not created if the task is not run. With your current code, doing it at configuration phase, this file would always get created if you start Gradle, no matter if the task will run or not.

Comment: The problem there is that my logFile is created in a relative path which is defined by the **workingDir** property of the **Exec** type. Trying to bring it up to the **doFirst** function will not work since doFirst has not the functionality of the "Exec" type. Using an absolute path is not a solution. Also the **buildDir** property wouldn't help since I already copied the files into a folder called **production** for the sake of a deployment tryout

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to use the working dir property of the task at execution time? Of course you can. And even if not, nothing prevents you to define the logFile variable at configuration time already. As you can see in my example I didn't put that line in the execution phase. Would make sense though of course. No need to do that call at execution phase already.